# How to get an item from javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Sorry maybe very easy for someone, but how can I get the value from this array?

```
        this.optionSelect = [{value: 'aa', name: 'ccc'}];
```

I tried :

```
console.log( this.optionSelect['value']);
```

also `

```
console.log( this.optionSelect[0]);`
```

Comment: Try `this.optionSelect[0].value`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access and process nested objects and arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-and-arrays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reach this value by the following. Arrays are Indexed, the 0 is which index in the array you are accessing so. [JavaScript Arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp).

```
this.optionSelect[0] will be -> {value: 'aa', name: 'ccc'};
```

Then add `.value` as the key you want to access of the object. [Property access](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors).

```
console.log(this.optionSelect[0].value);
```

Answer (score 4):

They are multiple level to need to interact with.

First level is the array. You can see it's an array because of the delimiting characters **[ ]** :

**[**`{value: 'aa', name: 'ccc'}`**]**;

You access the first element of the array using an index, like : `this.optionSelect[0]`

---

Then you have to deal with an object. You can see it's an object because of the delimiting characters **{ }** :

**{**`value: 'aa', name: 'ccc'`**}**

To access an object, you have to use the name of the key you want, like : `obj.value` or `obj['value']`.

Both notation works.

---

Now do both in the same line :

```
this.optionSelect[0].value
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the `value` of the first item in the array:

```
const value = this.optionSelect[0].value;
```

Also try destructuring:

```
const [{ value }] = this.optionSelect;
```